# Display a webpage inside a swing application

Tags: java, swing

I would like to display a webpage inside a java swing application. Similar to a  when using HTML, but in java Swing. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: *"display a webpage"*  Is this a web page that you control?  If not, forget `JEditorPane` - it is not a browser component.

Comment: It's a webpage i control

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use a `JEditorPane`:

```
JEditorPane jep = new JEditorPane();
jep.setEditable(false);   

try {
  jep.setPage("http://www.yoursite.com");
}catch (IOException e) {
  jep.setContentType("text/html");
  jep.setText("<html>Could not load</html>");
} 

JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(jep);     
JFrame f = new JFrame("Test HTML");
f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
f.getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
f.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800,600));
f.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help will check out both of the above solutions

Comment: The constructor JScrollPane(JEditorPane) is undefined

Answer (score 6):

You might want to look at http://java.dzone.com/articles/web-browser-your-java-swing.

JxBrowser lets you display any webpage,by embedding a browser into your swing application.

Comment: Worth noting that JxBrowser is proprietary and costs quite some.