# Java GUI - Web Browser and Opening Link

Tags: java, url, web

I am creating a game and I made a Launcher. I have seen on other games made out of Java (Like MineCraft) have a webpage on the launcher. I was woundering how to put a webpage on a Java Swing GUI panel. I would also like to know how to open their browser up to a link with a button.
                                                                             Thanks,

Blockquote

Comment: Maybe this help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020854/embed-firefox-browser-in-java-swing and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601676/display-a-webpage-inside-a-swing-application (seems that it is a duplicate of this one)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To open a url in the system's web browser you can use [java.awt.Desktop.browse(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29). This allows you to keep your Java code platform independent, and even allows you to check to see if an operation is supported before trying to use it.

To load a web page within Java, I've had some success using the [JavaFX WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/web/WebView.html).

Comment: ggovan's answer is correct, even for opening a web page in a Swing Panel, as you can place the `WebView` in a [JFXPanel](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/embed/swing/JFXPanel.html).  See Oracle's tutorial: [SimpleSwingBrowser](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm).

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.awt.Desktop;
import java.net.URI;

class URLBrowsing 
{

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    {

        try 
        {
            // Create Desktop object
            Desktop d=Desktop.getDesktop();

            // Browse a URL, for example www.facebook.com
            d.browse(new URI("http://www.facebook.com")); 
            // This open facebook.com in your default browser.
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```