# Open web site into an Applet

Tags: java, html, swing, applet, awt

I'm working in an application based on Applets, with Swing and awt. My current task is to replace the call to an applet by a given web site, let say instead of opening an old applet I have to open the address https://stackoverflow.com/. After a short discussion with my technical supervisor he advised me to enbed the web site into the applet.

The issue is the following:

- Can We embed a web site into an applet?
- If yes, how? May be embedding the site into a JPanel, isn't it?

I did found plenty of ways of embedding an applet into a html page but not the other way around.

Thanks a lot in advance!

EDIT: As a matter of completing the question I finally found some links on Stackoverflow that may help someonelse:

- [Best Java/Swing browser component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/145863/best-java-swing-browser-component?lq=1)
- [Embed Firefox browser in Java Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020854/embed-firefox-browser-in-java-swing?lq=1)
- [Display a webpage inside a swing application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10601676/display-a-webpage-inside-a-swing-application)

Comment: *"After a short discussion with my technical supervisor he advised me to enbed the web site into the applet."*  That's astonishingly poor advice.  What is the point of all this?

Comment: The idea is to replace the call to an applet which implements some search functionalities using web-services by a web site that has already implemented much better and advanced search features for the same items. They are basically publicly known products description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am unsure if this will work in an applet since the example is for desktop use, however see this [Oracle Example](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/SimpleSwingBrowser.java.htm) on creating a Swing Browser.

This utilizes the [WebEngine](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html) class as part of JavaFX.